# How can I access the deserialization context in CustomCreationConverter.Create()?

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to access other deserialized property values of the current target object when determining the correct type to return from a CustomCreationConverter.

I.e. in the BeeConverter.Create() method below, I want to access something like GetCurrentTarget() that will give me back the (partially populated) current object instance. Is there perhaps some event or callback that allows me to store a ref to the current target?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class B
{
    public int IntProp;
}

public class D1 : B
{
    public string StringProp;
}

public class D2 : B
{
    public decimal DecimalProp;
}

public class Thingy
{
    public int Selector;
    public B DerivedProp;
}

public class BeeConverter : CustomCreationConverter<B>
{
    public override B Create(Type objectType)
    {
        var theThingy = GetCurrentTarget();
        if (theThingy == null) return null;
        return theThingy.Selector == 1 ? new D1() as B : new D2();
    }

    private Thingy GetCurrentTarget()
    {
        // ????
    }
}

public class ConverterTests : TestFixtureBase
{
    [Test]
    public void CanDeserializeDerivedType()
    {
        var testObject = new Thingy { Selector = 1, DerivedProp = new D1 { StringProp = "42" } };
        string stream = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObject);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thingy>(stream, new BeeConverter());
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(D1), result.DerivedProp);
        Assert.AreEqual("42", (result.DerivedProp as D1).StringProp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have done some more research and it seems this is not a viable approach. The accepted way to deal with derived types in the serialization stream is to use the JsonSerializerSettings class:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
string stream = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObject, Formatting.None, settings);
// ...
TestClass result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(stream, settings);
```